# MethodError: 'convert' has no method mathing convert(::T) when instantiating a type

Tags: types, julia

I have a composite type like this:

```
type CPUEmulator
  memory::Vector{Int64}

  CPUEmulator(memory::Vector{Int64}) = new(memory)
end
```

When I try to instantiate it like this,

```
myCPU = CPUEmulator([1,2])
```

I get the following error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{CPUEmulator}, ::Array{Int64,1})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor CPUEmulator(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  CPUEmulator(::Any, !Matched::Any)
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)
```

In the documentation example,
you have a type:

```
type Foo
  bar
  end
end
```

And you can instantiate it like this:

```
foo = Foo(1,2)
```

I can't figure what I have to do differently to instantiate my custom type

Comment: @Michael Ohlrogge: Thanks for looking into this. I'm running Julia on Atom Uber-Juno and the problem was there is a startup file called juliarc.jl  that automatically executes whenever Julia is run and I had no idea that this even existed. I don't know how it got there but there was  an old definition of my type running in it. After clearing this file, everything was running again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error - the code that you have works fine on my computer.  One thing about Julia is that it does not allow you to redefine custom types. It appears from the error message that the compiler is still working off an earlier definition of the `CPUEmulator` type that does not use the `Vector{Int64}` type specification that you have in the custom type definition and constructor you have in your question.

Thus, if you already entered one definition for `type CPUEmulator` and you are working in a given REPL session, for instance, you will need to close that REPL and reopen it.  Alternatively, you can just run your Julia program from the start with, e.g. `julia myscript.jl`.

Comment: `workspace()` is another convenient way to clean up workspace. In addition, one can retrieve old type definitions via `LastMain`.

Comment: As an additional comment, note that in the latest nightly for 0.6 at least, redefining types in the REPL is now supported.